# Visual Studio 2015 community without test options

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 COMMUNITY and I don't have tests options.

How can enable Test Project?. When I make right click in a method I don't have “Create Unit Tests” .

How can I enable the Unit Tests?
[image: Unit Test Project doesn't appear]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do that in old project types but in the new asp.net 5 core clr type projects there is not option for this. in a future tooling update the add tests option will be enabled in asp.net 5/dnx project creation templates. But you can add them manually, the new pattern uses xunit and a test project is just a class library package project. See [Getting Started with xUnit and DNX](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html)